# Latex error - "Could not start the command. "pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"

Tags: errors, pdftex, paths, compilation-error

I have just downloaded texmaker on my Mac, and when I try to compile a document, but I get the error "Could not start the command.
"pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex", and I don't know what to do. I am very new at this, so I might seem very confused

Comment: did you also installed a tex system like e.g. mactex? texmaker is only an editor.

Comment: I installed miktex

Comment: miktex is an unusual (but not necessarily incorrect) choice for a Mac (most mac users use mactex, a version of texlive) you will need to configure texmaker so it can find miktex most likely (sorry I don't have a mac, or texmaker so can not help)

Comment: Okay that makes sense, now I just installed mactex instead, and now when I try to compile I get another error instead, and that's "log file not found". Are you able to help with that?

Comment: imho (but I have no mac either) mactex comes with the editor texshop. Did you try it instead of texmaker?

Comment: As I say I can't really help as I don't have a mac or texmaker but I would guess that is essentially the same problem and your editor did not find latex so did not make a latex log file. If you show your editor configuration and the location where tex is installed I am sure a mac user will  see it and able to help

Comment: I don't like teashop that much as the pdf opens in a new document, whereas in texmaker is beside the tex file, so I thought I'd try that instead

Comment: @Sara TeXShop has a single window mode.

Comment: How do I turn that on?